# triggering setInterval on click happens once

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a div that its background-image changes every 5s, and I have a next button that should clear the setInterval timer and  change the background to the next one and trigger the setInterval again
but when I click the next button, it changes the background to the next one, but does not trigger the setInterval again.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
</div>
<a href="" id="arrow_right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

CSS Code:

```
#slideshow {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(../css/img/bg/slide1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    function bgrepeat(x){
        if(typeof(x)==='undefined') {
            $('#slideshow').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('#slideshow').css('background-image','url(ui/css/img/bg/slide' + i + '.jpg)');
                $('#slideshow').fadeIn(500);
            });
            i++;
            if(i == 5) {
                i = 1;
            }
        } else {
            $('#slideshow').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('#slideshow').css('background-image','url(ui/css/img/bg/slide' + x + '.jpg)');
                $('#slideshow').fadeIn(500);
            });
            x++;
            if(x == 5) {
                x = 1;
            }
        }
    };
    var timer = setInterval(bgrepeat , 5000);

    var bg = $('#slideshow').css('background-image');
    bg = bg.split('slide');
    var bgpath = bg[1];
    bgpath = bgpath.replace('.jpg")','');
    bgpath = parseInt(bgpath,10);

    $('#arrow_right').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bgpath++;
        if(bgpath == 5) {
            bgpath = 1;
        }
        $('#slideshow').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('#slideshow').css('background-image','url(ui/css/img/bg/slide' + bgpath + '.jpg)');
            $('#slideshow').fadeIn(500);
        });
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer2 = setInterval(bgrepeat(bgpath) , 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to `setInterval` not the result of its invocation.

```
timer2 = setInterval(function() {
    bgrepeat(bgpath) 
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You're using `timer2` where you should probably be using `timer`.
2. You're **calling** `bgrepeat(bgpath)` and passing its return value into `setInterval`, you're not passing `bgrepeat(bgpath)` into `setInterval`:

   You can do the latter like this:

   ```
   timer = setInterval(bgrepeat.bind(null, bgpath), 5000);
   ```

   `Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original function with a given `this` value (the first argument, we can just use `null`) and any further arguments you give it.

   It's an ES5 feature; if you need to support really old engines like IE8's, search for "Function bind shim" or "Function bind polyfill" to find shims/polyfills.